# Check_path in Silex Firewall or SecurityServiceProvider

Tags: forms, silex

i try to make a formular checked login in SILEX.

```
    $app['security.firewalls'] = array(
        'login' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/login$',
            'anonymous' => true
         ),
        'register' => array(
            'pattern'=>'^/register$',
            'anonymous' => true
        ),
        'chat' => array(
            'pattern'=>'^/chat$',
            'anonymous'=>false,
            //login_path: before authorisation  Check_path: path to check the date of the user
            'form'=>array('login_path'=>'/login','check_path' => '/chat/login_check'),
            'users'=> $app->share(function() use ($app){
                return new \resources\controller\UserProvider($app['db']);
            })
        )
    );
```

The thing i don't understand is that one:

```
form'=>array('login_path'=>'/login','check_path' => '/login_check'),
```

The /login is the route u will be routed to if u try to access the secured area. The /login_check should be the route to the check thing where u data will be checked....ist this right?

My question is: what should be behind the /login_check? I hope u can help me after hours of google...

Thank for ur help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. `/login` is the path user will be routed to authorize. The `/login_check` is the path to check authorization form post (username and password).

`/login` needs realization, just add route for this path and show authorization form.

```
<form method="post" action="/chat/login_check">
<input type="text" id="_username" name="_username" />
<input type="text" id="_password" name="_password" />
....
</form>
```

`/login_check` doesn't need realization, it is added and realized be security component implicit. This path should be in secure zone, so change it to `/chat/login_check`.

Also change pattern to `'pattern'=>'^/chat'`, to catch all requests beginning with /chat

Comment: Does it mean that i dont need an POST route for the form?

Comment: yes, it is added by security component automatically

Comment: ich have now the error:                                                                                   Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
NotFoundHttpException in HttpKernel.php line 128:
Unable to find the controller for path "/chat/login_check". The route is wrongly configured.

Comment: Do you register security service provider? `$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), [
    'security.firewalls' => $app['security.firewalls'])
]);`

Comment: sry im new here, i'll try it :)

Comment: Also you need to change the pattern to `pattern'=>'^/chat'`, to catch all requests beginning with `/chat`

Comment: So all request  beginning with `/chat` will be checked by firewall `chat`